# Conflict with jQuery toggle()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a fitness website, where users can click on a muscle group on a picture and it will select a bulletpoint, or vice versa. Here's a picture;

[image]

I have two jQuery functions, one to trigger the bulletpoints when the picture is clicked, and one to trigger the picture when the bulletpoints are clicked. They both work individually, but not when they both exist together.

At the moment, when you click on the 'chest' checkbox, it will illuminate and also display the chest highlight on the picture, so that's fine. However, when you click on the chest selector on the picture, it will not toggle the picture highlight, but it will change the checkbox. Any ideas?

Find the code below for the 'chest'

HTML

```
<!-- picture -->
<h1>Generate your workout</h1>
        <div id="anatomy">
            <div id="anatomy-highlights">
                <img id="img-anatomy-chest-check" src="img/workout-selection/anatomy-shoulders.png"/>
            </div>
          <div id="anatomy-chest" class="l highlight"></div>
          <img src="img/anatomy.png" style="float:left; padding-right:20px;"/>
        </div>


<!-- CHECKBOX -->
<div class="custom-check">
    <input class="body-part" type="checkbox" id="anatomy-chest-check"/>
    <label for="anatomy-chest-check"></label>
    </div>
    Chest
```

CSS

```
#anatomy-highlights img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
/* LINK PICTURE AND BODY PART CHECK BOXES*/

$(".highlight").click(function(){
    $("#anatomy-highlights #img-" + this.id + "-check").toggle();
    $("#" + this.id + "-check").trigger('click');
});

/* LINK BODY PART CHECK BOXES TO PICTURE*/

$(".body-part").click(function(){
    $("#anatomy-highlights #img-" + this.id).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Id's should be unique,  jQuery selectors won't work as you expect

Comment: andrew is right, and also you can use something like: $("#anatomy-highlights").find().slideTogle();

Comment: To which elements are you referring?

pics have id="img-anatomy-part-check"
boxes have id="anatomy-part-check"
selector for pics have id="anatomy-part"

Comment: @ChrisWness There should __only be__ 1 element with any id. More than 1 elements with same ids should not be there.

Comment: substitute the word 'part' for the body part in question and they're all unique ids - I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: `<div id="anatomy-shoulders" class="l highlight"></div>` and `<div id="anatomy-shoulders" class="r highlight"></div>` -- both those elements have the **same id**.

Comment: OK, poor example of a part to choose perhaps. I'll fix that, but it doesn't work with unique IDs either.

Comment: Next you'll have to define what "does not work" means. When you try it, what happens? What should happen instead?

Comment: I'll just edit this and start again :)

Comment: Edited with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you call `toggle()` twice:

1. user clicks on `.highlight`, you call `toggle()`, then `trigger('click')` on your checkbox
2. checkbox click handler gets called and calls `toggle()` the second time

Just remove the `toggle()` call from `.highlight` click handler.

Comment: Wonderful - thanks! It didn't occur to me that it was calling the other accidentally.